# How to keep the same fragment when rotation changes with using viewmodel?

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm, kotlin

I have a bottom navigation view with 3 buttons(popular,discover,favorite) on it. Each one shows their own fragments (popularFragment,discoverFragment,favoriteFragment). When app runs for the first time, it shows popularFragment by default and if i click discover or favorite buttons, their own fragments shows up and that is absolutely what i want but the problem is if rotation changes, popularFragment shows again.

I want to solve that problem with viewModel but i'm totaly new to Android architecture. This is my code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        popularFragment = FragmentPopular()
        discoverFragment = FragmentDiscover()
        favoritesFragment = FragmentFavorites()

        setFragment(popularFragment)

        navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(onNavigationItemSelectedListener)
    }

    fun setFragment(fragment: Fragment){
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_main, fragment).commit()
    }
```

So how can i solve this problem with using viewModel?

Comment: Why do you need a viewModel for solving this problem ?

Comment: Isn't it the best way to solve rotation problems?

Comment: It depends what do you need. What do you want to save to a ViewModel?

Every time when you rotate the screen - your fragments are destroyed and activity will recreated. In your onCreate() - you create a new instance of fragments every time when the method is invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you can do it with putting your data to the bundle and then check bundle != null

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("name", "David");
    outState.putInt("age", 17);
}
```

Add this check to your onCreate()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    …
    if(savedInstanceState != null)
    {
         savedInstanceState.getString("name");
         savedInstanceState.getInt("age");
    }
}
```

Or you can do it in this way:

Add this config to your activity:

```
<activity android:name=".com.somepackage.MyActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden" > </activity>
```

Then your edit text values to onSaveInstanceState

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
     outState.putCharSequence(KEY_TITLE, et_text.getText().toString());
 }
```

And get your saved values through onViewStateRestored

```
 @Override
public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);

    String savedTitle = null;
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        savedTitle = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_TITLE);
        et_text.setText(
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm doing it with first way you said but my "onSaveInstanceState()" method is not being called. Should i call it manually in onDestroy() method?

Comment: No, you shouldn't do that. 

Check this link to more clear understanding how the onSavedInstanceState() works
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)